# Delphi DateTimePicker disable certain dates

Tags: delphi

Hi I am rather new to coding and have to do a project for school where i have to save accommodation bookings in a database etc.
So in my program users select their arrival date and departure date in with a DateTimePicker which i then store in my database. I just don't know how i can now disable these dates when a new user logs in and wants to select their arrival or departure date for the same accommodation. Is there any feature for this or just to change the colour of those cells at least? The min and max date value don't really work for this as i can't disable a certain period? Just wondering if someone has any suggestions?

Thanks Stefan!

Comment: Place code in the TDateTimePicker's OnChange event and check if the date is valid or not. If not, disable the "OK" button and write an error message on your form. If valid, enable the "OK" button and clear the error message.

There's no built-in way for it - you have to code the validation by looking in the database yourself.

Comment: Instead of the `TDateTimePicker`, you could look at `Samples.TCalendar` component, in the `Vcl.Samples.Calendar` unit. It is based on `TCustomGrid` and exposes the `OnDrawCell()` event, in which you can check if the date to be painted is vacant or occupied and set e.g. color accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at the `TMonthCalendar` component. It has an `OnGetMonthBoldInfo` event that you are can use to bold/unbold individual dates.